# How much is the output voltage Vo

Tags: voltage, capacitor, inductor

Suppose we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPyAkG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will Vo be 0 or 1V?Both voltages seem correct.At DC the inductor acts like a short so in that sense the answer is 0V.But after we make the circuit ,current will flow in the capacitor charging it so in that sense the answer is 1V.Which one is it?

Comment: One way to tell is at steady state, capacitors can be replaced by an open. while inductors can be replaced by a short. Then is is easy to see.

Comment: @RussellH but where does the charge go which charged the capacitor in the first place?It disappears?

Comment: The capacitor doesn't get charged in the first place. (At least if you view the circuit at its DC equilibrium.)

Comment: @appliedSciences, The charge flows from the capacitor through the inductor.

Comment: @JonathanS. at t=0+ the current inside the inductor is 0.So it must flow inside the capacitor.

Comment: @appliedSciences, you should simulate using LTspice or Microcap

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I assume that you have a switch in series with the voltage source that you are closing at t=0 (which you have not shown in the figure).

You are confused between the initial value at t=0+ and the final value at t=infinity. At t=0+, yes, current will flow into the cap and build a voltage but that would not sustain for ever. Eventually at t=infinity, Vo has to become 0.